# What math technique was used to proceed from step 1 to step 2?

Tags: permutations, factorial, factoring

In my Math textbook under the Permutations unit, one of the example questions is as follows: **Show that 100! + 99! = 101(99!) without using technology.**

After the question, the example breaks the question down for you as done below:

**100! + 99! = 100(99!) + 99!**

= **99!(100+1)**

= **99!(101)**

= **101(99!)**

Now, my source of confusion stems from the transition from step 1 to step 2. Step 1 being the first line of the solution and step 2 being the second. I understand 100! is the same as 100(99!), but everything else after that doesn't make any sense to me. Could someone help clarify this for me?

Thank you.

Comment: It is called the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of natural numbers: $$a\times(b+c)=(a\times b)+(a\times c)$$ for all natural numbers $a, b$ and $c.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
100! + 99! &= 100(99!) + 99! \tag1\\
&= 99!(100+1) \tag2\\
&= 99!(101) \tag3\\
&= 101(99!) \tag4
\end{align}

- $(2)$ is distributive law $ab + ac = a (b + c)$ with $a = 99!$, $b = 100$ and $c = 1$.
- $(4)$ is because multiplication is commutative: $ab = ba$

Answer (score 3):

To go to the second line they used the fact that $99!=1(99!)$ and the distributive principle.  There is a common factor of $99!$ in both terms on the right of line 1.  From line 2 to line 3 they just added and to line 4 they used the commutative principle.  If they hadn't commuted the terms in going from line 1 to line 2 they wouldn't have had the third line.